# VSCode - debugging an iframe inside a web application with vscode-chrome-debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

Using the latest VS Code and the excellent Chrome Debug extension.

I have one site that I can't get debugging to work and it's because the code I want to debug is in an iframe.  Just running the page in the frame won't work for me (because auth and postMessage and more).

The folder structure in Chrome DevTools looks like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zGBY.jpg.  I want to debug the wfm folder selected, which is what I have open in VSCode.

The mapping as hosted by the web server is (though I can't hit this directly - this is what Chrome maps to if I try to use their workspace->code automap): 
https://localhost:4300/contact-center/components/wfm

I don't see any way to tell the plugin that I want to debug this iframe in launch.json, but for completeness here's what I have so far:

```
{
        "name": "Launch with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "https://localhost:4300/dca",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "userDataDir": "/Users/${env.USER}/Library/Application\\ Support/Google/ChromePersonal",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

Comment: Came across the same problem, can't debug inside an iframe (or html object tag). Anyone find a fix?

Comment: Same, can see the context in Chrome, and the source maps, but VSCode seems only able to debug context of outer most frame.

Comment: This issue appears to be tracked on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/786

Comment: @deandob & op - I just setup an equivalent source map debug configuration for Firefox using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-firefox-debug and it works fine. It's mostly on 1:1 configuration parity with the Chrome tools so was quite easy to setup.

Comment: Unfortunately our application has to support Chrome as the primary browser so our debugging has to be in Chrome. This rules out our team using VS Code for web development! It works a little better in Visual Studio with Chrome as the target browser but still a bit inconsistent inside an <object> or <iframe>.

Answer (score 0):

Hah, it's been 5 years! I faced the same problem and switched to using [VS Code Debugger for Firefox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug) to debug an Outlook add-in.

`.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Firefox: Attach",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "url": "https://addin.example.com",
      "tabFilter": "https://outlook.office.com/*",
      "preLaunchTask": "Firefox debugger",
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "webpack:///",
          "path": "${webRoot}/"
        },
        {
          "url": "webpack://./",
          "path": "${webRoot}/"
        },
        {
          "url": "webpack:///**",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        },
        {
          "url": "webpack:///node_modules/",
          "path": null
        }
      ],
      "skipFiles": [
        "chrome://**",
        "moz-extension://**",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "log": {
        "consoleLevel": {
          "PathConversion": "Error",
          "SkipFilesManager": "Error",
          "DebugConnection": "Error",
          "ThreadActorProxy": "Error",
          "TabActorProxy": "Error",
          "SourceMappingThreadActorProxy": "Error",
          "SourceActorProxy": "Error",
          "net": "Error",
          "ConsoleActorProxy": "Error",
          "ConsoleActor": "Error",
          "FirefoxDebugSession": "Error",
          "FirefoxDebugAdapter": "Error",
          "RootActorProxy": "Error",
          "TabDescriptorActorProxy": "Error",
          "DataBreakpointsManager": "Error",
          "BreakpointsManager": "Error",
          "SourceAdapter": "Error",
          "SourceMappingSourceActorProxy": "Error",
          "SourceMappingInfo": "Error",
          "ThreadPauseCoordinator": "Error",
          "FrameActorProxy": "Error",
          "ObjectGripActorProxy": "Error",
          "ThreadCoordinator": "Error",
          "default": "Debug"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- `"preLaunchTask": "Firefox debugger"` - comes from `.vscode/tasks.json`
- `"url": "https://addin.example.com"` - iframe's URL
- `"tabFilter": "https://outlook.office.com/*"` - instructs to search iframe in specific tabs

`.vscode/tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Firefox debugger",
      "osx": {
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --start-debugger-server"
      },
      "windows" : {
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" -start-debugger-server"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I need something like that for chrome
any ideas?